# Laravel moderate errors on save()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In this sample code below how would I moderate errors such as Eloquent could not save or update fields or break SQL connection?

```
$user = new User;

$user->name = 'John';

$user->save();
```

Comment: Could you rephrase? If the database is in working order and the connection details are correct you won't be getting SQL connection errors..

Comment: @SamV then in all of live time. save() method can insert or update for database and always connection and request is correct?????????

Answer (score 5):

The save() method for eloquent returns a boolean on failure and a collection object on success, so you can display an error if the save() method returns false;

For example:

```
$user = new User;

$user->name = 'John';

if($user->save()){
    return Redirect::to('users')->with('message', sprintf('User: "%s" successfully saved', $user->name));
} else{
    return Redirect::to('users')->with('message', 'Failed to create user');
}
```

Here's the eloquent save function in detail:

http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save

You may also want to look at model events:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events

EDIT:
For your other question to catch a database connection error you can use a try/catch block such as:

```
try{
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password))){
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    } else{
        //Authentication failed
        return Redirect::to('home')->with('message', 'Authentication failed, username/password inccorrect');
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    return Redirect::to('home')->with('message', sprintf('Failed to connect to database: %s', $e));
}
```

Comment: for test after change mysql connection password. try,catch does not working and i get this error: `PDOException
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Well it depends on where you place the try catch block. If your entire app requires a constant connection to the database you may want to place it somewhere globally such as your routes.php file.